# Remove bottom margin on FAB in flutter scaffold

Tags: ios, flutter

Trying to create a bottom fab that lies at the very bottom of the screen. however there's additional padding being added below the button on large iphone devices. How do i remove it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Container(height: 56, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Example]

Comment: floatingActionButton is placed within the safe area, which excludes status bar, notch and navigation bars.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line in the main function

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
      SystemUiMode.manual,
      overlays: [
        SystemUiOverlay.top, // Shows Status bar and hides Navigation bar
      ],
    );
```

like this :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: [
          SystemUiOverlay.top, // Shows Status bar and hides Navigation bar
        ],
      );
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          child: Container(height: 56, color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: this results in the same bottom padding as in my image above, only without the system button at the bottom.

Comment: @user20824592 because the floating action
now you can show the new edit

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems the best option is not to use Scaffold's `floatingActionButton` property at all but rather create a custom FAB by wrapping the Scaffold's body with `Stack` like so:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Move FAB Lower'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Text('Content'),
            ),
            PositionedFab(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PositionedFab extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double fabMargin = 16.0;

    return Positioned(
      bottom: fabMargin,
      right: fabMargin,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```